# Rails + JQuery Pass additional params with $post & serialize

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable list which works, but in order to pass in additional params, I need to append to the update-url like this:

```
data-update-url="<%= sort_schedule_tasks_url + '?day=' + day.to_s %>"
```

And then it's posted like this:

```
$.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'));
```

I'd rather be able to create additional data attributes, what is the best way to do this?